# Bicep App Service Environment deployment fails after initial deployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am currently using Bicep to deploy an ILB ASE v3 inside my vNet. My Bicep file is based on the latest release [Bicep v0.10 release](https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/releases). The Network Security Group has been configured inline with the [Microsoft ASE Network consideration doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info#network-security-groups)

The problem I am experiencing is if I run the deployment the first time it works without issue. However, every time I redeploy it fails with a "Not Supported" error as below.

```
{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "An error occurred when updating the ase-eun-h1s01-dev-iac entry : {\"Message\":\"Not supported.\"}",
  "details": [
    {
      "message": "An error occurred when updating the ase-eun-h1s01-dev-iac entry : {\"Message\":\"Not supported.\"}"
    },
    {
      "code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

It gives me no further inforamtion. So, what I am left wondering is if deploying the template to update the ILB ASE or just as part of a subsequent pipeline run is supported?

**Main Bicep file (snippet)**

```
module appServiceEnvironmentv3 'br/Compute:asev3:v0.1' = {
  name: 'asev3-${appServiceEnvironment.name}-${uniqueString(appServiceEnvironment.name)}'
  scope: appServiceEnvironment.resourceGroup != '' ? resourceGroup(appServiceEnvironment.resourceGroup)  : resourceGroup()
  params: {
    name: appServiceEnvironment.name
    location: location
    subnetResourceId: resourceId(appServiceEnvironment.subnet.virtualNetworkResourceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', appServiceEnvironment.subnet.virtualNetworkName, appServiceEnvironment.subnet.name)
    diagnosticStorageAccountId: resourceId(appServiceEnvironment.diagnosticSettings.storageAccount.resourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', appServiceEnvironment.diagnosticSettings.storageAccount.accountName)
    diagnosticWorkspaceId: resourceId(appServiceEnvironment.diagnosticSettings.logAnalyticsWorkspace.resourceGroup, 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', appServiceEnvironment.diagnosticSettings.logAnalyticsWorkspace.accountName)      
    tags: appServiceEnvironment.tags
  }
}
```

**App Service Environment Bicep file**

```
@description('Required. Name of the App Service Environment.')
@minLength(1)
param name string

@description('Optional. Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Required. ResourceId for the subnet.')
param subnetResourceId string

@description('Optional. Resource ID of the diagnostic storage account.')
param diagnosticStorageAccountId string = ''

@description('Optional. Resource ID of the diagnostic log analytics workspace.')
param diagnosticWorkspaceId string = ''

@description('Optional. Resource tags.')
param tags object = {}

//Default Values
var allowNewPrivateEndpointConnections = false
var clusterSettings = [
  {
    name: 'DisableTls1.0'
    value: '1'
  }
]
var dedicatedHostCount = 0
var dnsSuffix = ''
var frontEndScaleFactor = 15
var ftpEnabled = true
var internalLoadBalancingMode = 'Web, Publishing'
var inboundIpAddressOverride = ''
var ipsslAddressCount = 0
var kind = 'ASEv3'
var multiSize = ''
var remoteDebugEnabled = true
var upgradePreference = 'None'
var userWhitelistedIpRanges = []
var zoneRedundant = false

//Default Values
var diagnosticLogCategoriesToEnable = ['allLogs']
var diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays = 365
var diagnosticSettingsName = 'diag-${name}-asev3-log'
var diagnosticEventHubAuthorizationRuleId = ''
var diagnosticEventHubName = ''

var diagnosticsLogsSpecified = [for category in filter(diagnosticLogCategoriesToEnable, item => item != 'allLogs'): {
  category: category
  enabled: true
  retentionPolicy: {
    enabled: true
    days: diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays
  }
}]

var diagnosticsLogs = contains(diagnosticLogCategoriesToEnable, 'allLogs') ? [
  {
    categoryGroup: 'allLogs'
    enabled: true
    retentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays
    }
  }
] : diagnosticsLogsSpecified

//Telemetry
var enableDefaultTelemetry = true
resource defaultTelemetry 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments@2021-04-01' = if (enableDefaultTelemetry) {
  name: 'pid-47ed15a6-730a-4827-bcb4-0fd963ffbd82-${uniqueString(deployment().name, location)}'
  properties: {
    mode: 'Incremental'
    template: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      resources: []
    }
  }
}

// Create ASE v3
resource appServiceEnvironment 'Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments@2022-03-01' = {
  name: name
  kind: kind
  location: location
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    clusterSettings: clusterSettings
    dedicatedHostCount: dedicatedHostCount != 0 ? dedicatedHostCount : null
    dnsSuffix: dnsSuffix
    frontEndScaleFactor: frontEndScaleFactor
    internalLoadBalancingMode: internalLoadBalancingMode
    ipsslAddressCount: ipsslAddressCount != 0 ? ipsslAddressCount : null
    multiSize: !empty(multiSize) ? any(multiSize) : null
    upgradePreference: upgradePreference
    userWhitelistedIpRanges: !empty(userWhitelistedIpRanges) ? userWhitelistedIpRanges : null
    virtualNetwork: {
      id: subnetResourceId
      subnet: last(split(subnetResourceId, '/'))
    }
    zoneRedundant: zoneRedundant
  }
}

resource configuration 'Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/configurations@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'networking'
  parent: appServiceEnvironment
  properties: {
    allowNewPrivateEndpointConnections: allowNewPrivateEndpointConnections
    ftpEnabled: ftpEnabled
    inboundIpAddressOverride: inboundIpAddressOverride
    remoteDebugEnabled: remoteDebugEnabled
  }
}

resource appServiceEnvironment_diagnosticSettings 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = if (!empty(diagnosticStorageAccountId) || !empty(diagnosticWorkspaceId)) {
  name: !empty(diagnosticSettingsName) ? diagnosticSettingsName : '${name}-diagnosticSettings'
  properties: {
    storageAccountId: !empty(diagnosticStorageAccountId) ? diagnosticStorageAccountId : null
    workspaceId: !empty(diagnosticWorkspaceId) ? diagnosticWorkspaceId : null
    eventHubAuthorizationRuleId: !empty(diagnosticEventHubAuthorizationRuleId) ? diagnosticEventHubAuthorizationRuleId : null
    eventHubName: !empty(diagnosticEventHubName) ? diagnosticEventHubName : null
    logs: diagnosticsLogs
  }
  scope: appServiceEnvironment
}

@description('The resource ID of the App Service Environment.')
output resourceId string = appServiceEnvironment.id

@description('The resource group the App Service Environment was deployed into.')
output resourceGroupName string = resourceGroup().name

@description('The name of the App Service Environment.')
output name string = appServiceEnvironment.name

@description('The location the resource was deployed into.')
output location string = appServiceEnvironment.location
```

Comment: I'd suggest raising an issue on the repository for that team to advise. https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/issues

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have raised the issue in Github - https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/issues/3331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved as part of this [Merge](https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/pull/3340)

The fix was specifically around the DNSSuffix property:

```
dnsSuffix: !empty(dnsSuffix) ? dnsSuffix : null
```